# Не выполняется SQL-запрос с двумя параметрами

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Есть запрос с двумя параметрами,после выполнения ничего не выдает.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `SELECT-LIKE`(IN par VARCHAR(40),IN par1 VARCHAR(40))
BEGIN
 SELECT * FROM table.personal WHERE @par LIKE CONCAT('%',@par1,'%');
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Параметр нельзя использовать в качестве имени столбца/таблицы.
Используйте динамический SQL для этого.

Comment: Спасибо,уже понял.Пошел обходным путем.